# How can I access an instance of an object in different classes / pages without a widget tree context?

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I am trying to access an instance of an RtcEngine object for AgoraIO from another class/page that doesn't have a widget tree, and therefore no context to refer to with Provider.

First I'm calling initPlatformState() from this class in order to initialize the RtcEngine engine:

```
class Game extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _GameState createState() => _GameState();
}

class _GameState extends State<Game> implements GameListener {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   Agora().initPlatformState(widget.playerId);
  }
}
```

initPlatformState initializes the RtcEngine by creating an instance called engine that I need to use later on to call other methods.  This class also contains the method I want to call later using the same instance to adjustVolume...

```
class Agora {
  RtcEngine engine;
// Initialize the agora app
  Future<void> initPlatformState(int playerId) async {

    RtcEngine engine = await RtcEngine.create(APP_ID);
  }
  void adjustVolume(int uid, int volume) {
   
    engine.adjustUserPlaybackSignalVolume(uid, volume);
   
  }
}
```

This is the class that I want to call adjustVolume from.   I was considering using Provider to pass the instance to this class but it extends another class and it doesn't have a widget tree with context so I'm not sure how thats possible or if there is a better way.

```
class Remote extends Component {

final int id;

Remote(this.id);

@override
void update() {
      //this is where I'm trying to access the engine instance that was created to call adjustUserPlaybackSignalVolume method

 }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to reuse that instance of "engine" given my situation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to the StackOverflow! It seems like you haven't passed the reference in the constructor therefore you are calling a method on a null pointer. Can you share more code, spesifically the code of the page where you call `engine.adjustUserPlaybackSignalVolume(uid, volume);`?

Comment: @easeccy, thanks for trying to help.   I'm not exactly clear what you mean by "passing the reference in the constructor"  In the page I'm calling that method, I don't have any other relevant code.   I'm only importing the previous file where I declared the RtcEngine called agora.dart  Then the specific code I'm calling with is 'Agora().engine.adjustUserPlaybackSignalVolume(this.id, 100);'  The id gets passed based on the error, but I think it doesn't recognize that my "engine" is the same as the one that I used to create the RtcEngine.

Comment: In other words, I think the problem is "engine" is first getting initialized inside a Future method and so I can't use that same instance in another method...eithe in the same class or a different class.  I 'm not familiar enough with flutter to know if I can get around that or even if it's possible.

Comment: Put all of your relevant code so I can give suggestions.

Comment: @easeccy, I added all relevant code at end of question with explanations.

Comment: Can you use debugger to check the state of `engine` just before you call volume method on it?

Comment: @easeccy, state of `engine` at breakpoint right after `initPlatformState()` is `engine: RtcEngine`.   Then at another breakpoint right before `adjustVolume()` gets called `engine: null`.   Again, it makes sense since engine is being instantiated inside a Future method, but I just don't know how to reuse it in other methods.

Comment: This is a state management question. It is a very large domain. You can Google "flutter state management" and get informed. Easiest and non-recommended way to fix this is to declare the engine in the state object and initialize it in `initState()`.

Comment: @easeccy, I know a little bit about state management options in Flutter.  I'm familiar with setState() on stateful widgets as well as provider package.  From what I understand though, they require a widget tree, right?  However, the Remote class I'm trying to use the engine object in doesn't have a widget tree so there is no context.   Is there a way around that?  Sorry for being so new with flutter.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being new. Please clear your question and put as much as code you can. I will try to point the lines to modify.

Comment: updated question with more detail.

Comment: Make Agora a service and inject it to your state.

Comment: @easeccy, can you please elaborate as I'm not familiar with how to do this.  If possible, using my code as an example?

Comment: Oh boy, lets have a discussion on Discord. I will explain dependency injection and state management to you. You might also remove the question on this platform. Enes#7446 is my Discord. Hit me up!